# LINQ Left Join -Where statement issue

Tags: c#, linq

I have *sort of* figured out the original question I had (although if there is a better way I'd love to hear it).  I'm having an issue now with the Where clause

```
where answer.TeacherID == "1234"
```

I need all 7 rows to return not just the 4 rows that have the TeacherID.  In my current statement (below), no matter where I put the Where it always just returns the 4 rows...  What am I doing incorrectly?

Here is my Updated LINQ statement (needing the `Where` clause still)

```
var resultSet = (from question in db.Questions
                 join TeacherDetail in db.AnswerDetails on question.QuestionID 
                 equals TeacherDetail.QuestionID into qListTeacher
                 from TeacherDetail in qListTeacher.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join answer in db.Answers on TeacherDetail.AnswerKey 
                 equals answer.AnswerKey into aList
                 from answer in aList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join LeaderDetail in db.AnswerDetails on question.QuestionID 
                 equals LeaderDetail.QuestionID
                 into qListLeader
                 from LeaderDetail in qListLeader.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new ProfessionalObject
                 {
                     QuestionID = question.QuestionID,
                     IndicatorID = question.ID,
                     QuestionDescription = question.Description,
                     AnswerKey = answer.AnswerKey,
                     TeacherID = answer.TeacherID,
                     LeaderID = answer.LeaderID,
                     StatusKey = answer.StatusKey,
                     TeacherAnswerDetailKey = (answer.TeacherID != null ? TeacherDetail.AnswerDetailKey : 0),
                     TeacherAnswerOptionKey = (answer.TeacherID != null ? TeacherDetail.AnswerOptionKey : 0),
                     TeacherComment = (answer.LeaderDPSID == null ? TeacherDetail.Comment : ""),
                     LeaderAnswerDetailKey = (answer.LeaderID != null ? LeaderDetail.AnswerDetailKey : 0),
                     LeaderAnswerOptionKey = (answer.LeaderID != null ? LeaderDetail.AnswerOptionKey : 0),
                     LeaderComment = (answer.LeaderDPSID != null ? LeaderDetail.Comment : ""),                                 
                     }).ToList();
```

I have Questions that I would like to package into my object regardless if there are answers to them.
I have a Leader and a Teacher that have the ability to answer these questions

**So I want a resultSet that would return All of the Questions and I want the Teacher Comments to go into the Teacher Properties 
and the Leader Comments to go into the Leader Properties.**

**For Example:**

```
QuestionID: 1, QuestionDescription: Question 1, TeacherComment = Null, LeaderComment = "Leader Answer" , TeacherID: 12345, LeaderID: 9999
QuestionID: 2, QuestionDescription: Question 2, TeacherComment = Null, LeaderComment = "Leader Answer 2", TeacherID: 12345, LeaderID: 9999
QuestionID: 3, QuestionDescription: Question 3, TeacherComment = "Teacher Answer", LeaderComment = NULL , TeacherID: 12345, LeaderID: NULL
QuestionID: 4, QuestionDescription: Question 4, TeacherComment = "Teacher Answer 2", LeaderComment = NULL , TeacherID: 12345, LeaderID: NULL
QuestionID 5, QuestionDescription: Question 5, TeacherComment = NULL, LeaderComment = NULL , TeacherID: NULL,  LeaderID: NULL
QuestionID 6, QuestionDescription: Question 6, TeacherComment = NULL, LeaderComment  = NULL , TeacherID: NULL,  LeaderID: NULL
QuestionID 7, QuestionDescription: Question 7, TeacherComment = NULL, LeaderComment = NULL, TeacherID: NULL,  LeaderID: NULL
```

The Answer table has a PK on the AnswerKey there is also a TeacherID and a LeaderID
The AnswerDetail Table contains the QuestionID and the Comments to the questions.

*I've tried adding where statements to split the Teacher Info (i.e. Where TeacherID != NULL and LeaderID == NULL
As well as for the Leader info (TeacherID != NULL and LeaderID !=NULL).  But they just limited my result set*

**Answer Records:**

```
AnswerKey: 1 TeacherID: 1234 LeaderID: 9999

AnswerKey: 5 TeacherID: 1234 LeaderID: NULL
```

**AnswerDetail Records:**

```
AnswerKey: 1 QuestionID: 1 Comment: Leader Answer

AnswerKey: 1 QuestionID: 2 Comment: Leader Answer 2

AnswerKey: 5 Question: 3 Comment: Teacher Answer

AnswerKey: 5 Question: 4 Comment: Teacher Answer 2
```

**Question Records:**

```
QuestionID: 1 QuestionDescription: Question #1

QuestionID: 2 QuestionDescription: Question #2

QuestionID: 3 QuestionDescription: Question #3

QuestionID: 4 QuestionDescription: Question #4

QuestionID: 5 QuestionDescription: Question #5

QuestionID: 6 QuestionDescription: Question #6

QuestionID: 7 QuestionDescription: Question #7
```

**UPDATE:**

The above resultSet returns the 7 questions correctly and the Comments are technically correct.  What I'm hoping to achieve is if the leader has comments then I want them to go into the Leader Properties and if the teacher has comments then I want them to go into the Teacher Properties.

The logic for the Leader is if the TeacherID != NULL and the LeaderID != NULL
The logic for the Teacher is if the TeacherID != NULL and the LeaderID == NULL

This is my class:

```
public class ProfessionalObject
{
    public int? QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string IndicatorID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionDescription { get; set; }
    public int? AnswerKey { get; set; }
    public string TeacherID { get; set; }
    public string LeaderID { get; set; }
    public int? StatusKey { get; set; }
    public int? TeacherAnswerDetailKey { get; set; }
    public int? TeacherAnswerOptionKey { get; set; }
    public string TeacherComment { get; set; }
    public int? LeaderAnswerDetailKey { get; set; }
    public int? LeaderAnswerOptionKey { get; set; }
    public string LeaderComment { get; set; }

    public ProfessionalObject()
    {
        QuestionID = 0;
        IndicatorID = "";
        QuestionDescription = "";
        AnswerKey = 0;
        TeacherID = "";
        LeaderID = "";
        StatusKey = 0;
        TeacherAnswerDetailKey = 0;
        TeacherAnswerOptionKey = 0;
        TeacherComment = "";
        LeaderAnswerDetailKey = 0;
        LeaderAnswerOptionKey = 0;
        LeaderComment = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up using @ShlomiBorovitz suggestion to break up my pieces and the join them at the end:

```
var questionSet = ( from question in Questions select question);
var TeacherAnswer = ( from detail in AnswerDetails 
                    join answer in Answers on detail.AnswerKey equals answer.AnswerKey
                    where answer.TeacherID == "12345" && answer.LeaderID == null
                    select new { detail, answer});

var LeaderAnswer = (from detail in AnswerDetails 
                    join answer in Answers on detail.AnswerKey equals answer.AnswerKey
                    where answer.TeacherID == "12345" && answer.LeaderID != null
                    select new { detail, answer});                                       



var combination = ( from q in questionSet
                    join tDetail in TeacherAnswer on q.QuestionID equals tDetail.detail.QuestionID into tList
                    from tDetail in tList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join lDetail in LeaderAnswer on q.QuestionID equals lDetail.detail.QuestionID into lList
                    from lDetail in lList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new {q,tList, lList });



var resultSet = (from combo in combination
                select new 
                {
                    QuestionID = (combo.q.QuestionID == null ? 0 : combo.q.QuestionID),
                    IndicatorID = combo.q.ID,
                    QuestionDescription = combo.q.Description,
                    TeacherAnswerKey = (combo.tList.Select(x => x.detail.AnswerKey).FirstOrDefault() == null ? 0 : combo.tList.Select(y => y.detail.AnswerKey).FirstOrDefault()),
                    LeaderAnswerKey = (combo.lList.Select(x => x.detail.AnswerKey).FirstOrDefault() == null ? 0 : combo.lList.Select(y => y.detail.AnswerKey).FirstOrDefault()),
                    TeacherID = (combo.tList.Select(y => y.answer.TeacherID).FirstOrDefault() == null ? "" : combo.tList.Select(y => y.answer.TeacherID).FirstOrDefault()),
                    LeaderID = (combo.lList.Select(x => x.answer.LeaderID).FirstOrDefault() == null ? "" : combo.lList.Select(y => y.answer.LeaderID).FirstOrDefault()),
                    TeacherStatusKey = (combo.tList.Select(x => x.answer.StatusKey).FirstOrDefault() == null ? 0 : combo.tList.Select(y => y.answer.StatusKey).FirstOrDefault()),
                    LeaderStatusKey = (combo.lList.Select(x => x.answer.StatusKey).FirstOrDefault() == null ? 0 : combo.lList.Select(y => y.answer.StatusKey).FirstOrDefault()),
                    TeacherAnswerDetailKey = (combo.tList.Select(x => x.answer.TeacherDPSID).FirstOrDefault() == null ? 0 : combo.tList.Select(y => y.detail.AnswerDetailKey).FirstOrDefault()),
                    TeacherAnswerOptionKey = (combo.tList.Select(x => x.answer.TeacherDPSID).FirstOrDefault() == null ? 0 : combo.tList.Select(y => y.detail.AnswerOptionKey).FirstOrDefault()),
                    TeacherComment = combo.tList.Select(y => y.detail.Comment).FirstOrDefault(),
                    LeaderAnswerDetailKey = (combo.lList.Select(x => x.answer.LeaderID).FirstOrDefault() == null ? 0 : combo.lList.Select(y => y.detail.AnswerDetailKey).FirstOrDefault()),
                    LeaderAnswerOptionKey = (combo.lList.Select(x => x.answer.LeaderDPSID).FirstOrDefault() == null ? 0 : combo.lList.Select(y => y.detail.AnswerOptionKey).FirstOrDefault()),
                    LeaderComment = combo.lList.Select(y => y.detail.Comment).FirstOrDefault(),
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: you don't actually need all these brackets (except for the last query, because of the call to `ToList`) :P

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz - What do you mean "brackets"?  Again thanks for your help.

Comment: it's the least important thing, but, I meant all these `( )` surrounding your queries. that's why I added ":P"

Answer (score 1):

That's what `Where` does. Filter the collection, from all the data which doesn't fits the condition.

You may remove the where, if you don't want to filter out those items

Comment: I need it to be more of a left join type of thing.  I know that the where clause will filter out the rows but I need the questions that don't have comments also to show up in my resultset

Comment: In my question you will see the "Example" of the resultSet I'm looking for.

Comment: I'll give you advice, because such big query is hard to debug and understand (especially if you're on the phone, like me). Create multiple simple queries, each of which would retrieve specific data, from some source - then combine them the the suited query (I'll look more closely on your query when I'll be near a computer)

Comment: Actually your breaking it up comment put me on the right path.

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: yes...  I'm having an issue now with the TeacherComment and the LeaderComment field...  I need the TeacherComment to be filled only if the LeaderID == null and the LeaderComment to be filled if the LeaderID != null && the TeacherID != null.  Ideally I'd like to not have to do the logic I'm doing in the select clause with all the ternary statements if possible.

Comment: If you didn't need the `TeacherDetail` data and `LeaderDetail` data for other fields, you could have filter them out with a `where` statement. but, you do need them, so you could use a `let` statement to get the comment or null, for each of them - but this is just as doing so in the `select` it self (actually, a `let` statement is translated to a call to `Select`).

Comment: Do you have an example of how the let is used?

Comment: for every question, there is an answer: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) ;)